# Why am i getting OneSignal.getNotificationPermission is not a function in my Next,js App

Tags: next.js, push-notification, onesignal

I am not getting the prompt to subscribe when i am trying to use OneSignal prompt function

I am trying to implement push notifications in my Next.js App using OneSignal.

i have placed the serviceworker in public folder and am registering and initializing it in index.js

```
index.js
export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register("/OneSignalSDKWorker.js")
        .then((registration) => {
          console.log(
            "Service Worker registration successful with scope: ",
            registration.scope
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Service Worker registration failed: ", error);
        });
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
        OneSignal.push(function () {
          OneSignal.init({
            appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID,
            notifyButton: {
              enable: true,
            },
            allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
          });
        });
      }     
  }, []);
...other code
```

i got a prompt to subscribe to notifications when i loaded the website for the first time and I can see that there is one user subscribed in the OneSignal dashboard.

My question is how can i prompt the subscription again to other users visiting and how can i send notifications to them?

when i try to initiate a prompt on clicking a button i dont get any prompt.

```
Header.js

const Header = () => {
  ...other code

  async function subscribe() {
 try {
      const permissionStatus = await Notification.permission;
      console.log("Permission", permissionStatus);
      if (permissionStatus !== "Permission granted") {
        OneSignal.push(function () {
          OneSignal.showNativePrompt();
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
 return (
       <header className="bg-white md:mx-auto md:px-4 text-black w-full sticky top-0 z-50">

        ...othercode

          <button onClick={subscribe}>Subscribe</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};
```

How can i prompt new users to subscribe for push notifications?